# Am I doing something dangerous with an AC to DC power supply?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, ac, battery-operated

I am new to electronics, and want to check to make sure I'm not missing critical points of safety, or setting myself up to do something stupid/dangerous.

The project I'd like to build is a compact system with a 12V 6A DC pump that is controlled by a Raspberry Pi Pico. I'll use a relay module to allow the pi to turn the pump on and off. The pump will only ever need to be on for a few seconds at a time, once or twice per day.

I see an AC power supply on aliexpress (WX-DC2412S) that has dual DC outputs (5V & 12V). That seems appealing to me, because my thinking is that the 5V output could power the Pi, and the 12V output could power the pump, allowing both components to run from a single power supply, keeping things compact. The power supply is an open PCB model, which makes me nervous. I understand that it would need an enclosure, but not sure on the best practices for enclosures of this kind, or how to ground the project itself. Is there a safe way forward to use a power supply of this kind, or are there better/safer options?

Ultimately, I'm not 100% confident implementing AC power without a good understanding of how to do it safely. So another thing I'm considering instead, is powering the pump with a portable 12V DC battery jump starter, that the pi can connect to as well via USB. With this option, will actuating the pump draw too much power and shut down the Pi?

If anyone can offer suggestions on either option, or point me to resources for further learning, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

Don't buy electronics from alibaba and similar platforms if you care about safety. Period.

Use reputable distributors, known brands and products with datasheets.

For your specific case, a Class II PSU would provide best safety. If you are certain that protective Earth installation in your building is proper, a Class I PSU will be also very safe.

Examples for Class I AC/DC supply which has 5 V and 12 V outputs are generic ATX power supplies for PCs.

Comment: Note: The ATX supply might be a good example for a Class I supply, but it would likely not work well powering the 5V and 12V loads. They are not lab supplies intended for powering any load in any way possible. The 6A pump will take more than 6A when starting up, and the power supply likely shuts down if you have 6A load and suddenly disconnect it so there is no load.

Comment: @Justme good points. My experience with even unbranded ATX supplies from trash was rather good, but some extreme load steps occur in this application so that may trigger them in undesired ways. It was the only thing that came to my mind which offered 5 and 12 V and was ubiquitous.

Comment: I once saw an engineer start a building fire that caused thousands of dollars worth of damage by wiring an ATX power supply with 40 A on the 12v rail to power a small amplifier circuit. When a wire accidentally shorted the power supply simply dumped current into the system until the room was burning and the sprinklers activated. Be very careful with ATX power supplies, they won't necessarily turn off in fault conditions the way a typical supply would because they're made to supply enormous current pulses to a CPU.